# Substring in mysql. Selecting some data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

```
ID         Value

A2424        1
A5355        2
A6363        3
A4634        4
AA_A2424     5
AA_A6363     6
```

I would like to select only those ID's that show up after AA_
so my output should be

```
ID     Value

AA2424    1
AA5355    2
```

I tried this but it isn't giving me the right output

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ID LIKE  SUBSTRING( 'AA_', 4, 8 )
```

Can anyout suggest??

Thanks

Comment: Your results don't match your original data. You might need to better explain yourself.

Comment: I have a ID after AA_. I need to select the ID and value of the ID that I have after AA_

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT ID
     , Value
FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 3) LIKE 'AA_%'
```

Comment: That would work but what if I have to select * for those samples )

Answer (score 0):

I guess your output isn't correct for this example table. It should be:

```
ID     Value

A2424     1
A6363     3
```

Here is a query to get what you need:

```
select * from AATable where id in
(select substring(id,4,100) from AATable where id like 'AA_%')
```